# Spring write Database undependend queries

Tags: mysql, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mysql-connector

I'm stuck to a little problem in my spring application.

I'm using a repository like this:

```
public interface TripRepository extends CrudRepository<TripEntity, Long>, Serializable {
  @Query("SELECT vt FROM TripEntity vt WHERE vt.opdDate "
      + " = TO_DATE(:operatingDay, 'DD.MM.YYYY') AND vt.lineId IN :lineIds")
  public List<TripEntity> findByDateAndLine(@Param("operatingDay") String operatingDay,
      @Param("lineIds") Collection<Long> lineIds);
```

My problem is the `to_date` function. In productive I'm using Oracle and all is fine. But for development I want to use a mysql database.

Is there a possibillity to write queries database undependent? Or maybe write two queries but use them depentend to the driver.

I would be happy if somone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you answered your own question; you write separate queries for each dialect that you're supporting.  You could perhaps write entirely separate queries for each dialect, or macro-like substitutions to replace certain syntax.  Exactly how you go about that depends on you application and programming skills, but is Far beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question.

Comment: database neutral code is a myth. Every rdbms product has its own unique implementation of SQL.  Every rdbms product has its own unique procedural language layered on top of its own unique implementation of SQL.  Every rdbms product has its own unique internal architecture and features, making 'best design practice' in one become 'worst design practice' in another.

Comment: Can't you use the [free XE edition](https://www.oracle.com/in/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html) for you development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure jpql defines TO_DATE function.

I would advise you to pass the date not as string but as a Date type and let ORM choose how the date is converted to appropriate db type.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. The solution was, strike out the to_date function from the query